# How to get the current id from the specific topic?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have a forum with topics, where each topic can be commented by other users. The relation i created is:

```
class Comment
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Topic", inversedBy="comments")
     */
    private $topic;
}
```

And the class Topic:

```
class Topic
{
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="topic")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="comment_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $comments;  
}
```

The problem is that when i create a comment, the topic_id column in the comments table is null. I'm not sure how to get the current topic id and set it to the comment. Here is my **addCommentAction() function** in the **CommentController**:

```
     /**
     * @Route("/comment/add", name="comment_add")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function addCommentAction(Request $request)
    {
        $comment = new Comment();

        $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $comment->setDateCreated(new \DateTime());

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($comment);
            $em->flush();


            $this->addFlash(
                'notice',
                'Comment Added Successfully !'
            );
        }
        return $this->render('comments/comment.add.html.twig', array(
            'commentsForm' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }
```

The path in the twig template:

```
<a href="{{ path('comment_add') }}" class="btn btn-lg btn-default">Leave a Comment</a>
```

Comment: I think you should pass `topic_id` via hidden input in your comment form or via url GET parameter (of action attribute of the form). If you render the form in the same action that you handle it, you will need the topic ID in url anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost done :) just try following

if Topic already exists

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$topic = $em->getRepository('YouBundle:Topic')->find( $topic_id );

if(false === $topic instanceof topic )
{
 // not found ...
}

$comment = new Comment();
$comment->setTopic( $topic )
// createForm....
```

if not, instead to look for one in DB, create one

```
$topic = new Topic();
$comment = new Comment();
$comment->setTopic( $topic );
```

**UPD:** as @Jakub Matczak said. You'll probably have to add a hidden field with topic_id to your form, since you don't want to get an Dropdown list with all available topics.

in your CommentForm Class in `buildForm` method

```
$builder->add('topic', HiddenType:class, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the topic on your comment entity. In your routing you must add the id of the topic then Symfony will automatically get the Topic entity with the [ParamConverter](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html)

Something like that should work :

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/comment/add", name="comment_add")
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function addCommentAction(Request $request, Topic $topic)
{
    $comment = new Comment();
    $comment->setTopic($topic);

    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $comment->setDateCreated(new \DateTime());

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($comment);
        $em->flush();


        $this->addFlash(
            'notice',
            'Comment Added Successfully !'
        );
    }
    return $this->render('comments/comment.add.html.twig', array(
        'commentsForm' => $form->createView()
    ));
}
```

Comment: I've tried your example, but i got exception in the twig template now, that says Some mandatory parameters are missing ("id") to generate a URL. I will add the template path which i use in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

A note: 
$form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
Shouldn't be "Comment"? I don't see any CommentType class in your description.

Also, you need to pass the topicId somehow when you are adding a new comment.
I would make a POST action for "/comment/add" and in the body I would send the topic id.

```
 // Rest of the imports...
 use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

 /**
 * @Route("/comment/add", name="comment_add")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function addCommentAction(Request $request)
{
    $comment = new Comment();

    $form = $this->createForm(CommentType::class, $comment);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $comment->setDateCreated(new \DateTime());

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $topicId = $request->request->get('topicId');
        $topic = $em->getRepository('Bundle:Topic')->find($topicId); // retrieve the topic id from the corresponding repository of the topic entity
        $comment->setTopic($topic); // setting the topic to the comment

        $em->persist($comment);
        $em->flush();


        $this->addFlash(
            'notice',
            'Comment Added Successfully !'
        );
    }
    return $this->render('comments/comment.add.html.twig', array(
        'commentsForm' => $form->createView()
    ));
}

You need also to add a repository from which you will retrieve the Topic objects. You need just an empty class named TopicRepository that should extend EntityRepository from Doctrine.
```

Beside this, you should also send the 'topicId' when you're doing the POST request from the client side.

Comment: I have a Class in Form Directory named CommentType, where i build the form, so it's working